# Static Error: No method in static FileAnalyzer has name 'analyzeFile'

Tags: java, static

I'm not sure what's wrong with the code I'm writing. I have 2 interfaces called TextInfo and TextAnalyzer.

I wrote an object called TextAttributes that implements the TextInfo interface. TextAttributes and TextInfo work just fine and do exactly what they are supposed to do.

I then wrote a class FileAnalyzer that implements TextAnalyzer and this is where the issue is happening. The following is the code:

```
public class FileAnalyzer implements TextAnalyzer {

    public TextInfo analyzeFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {  
        return new TextAttributes(fileName); 
    }
}

public interface TextAnalyzer {
    public TextInfo analyzeFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException;
}
```

FileAnalyzer is just supposed to return TextAttributes(fileName) which is a TextInfo object, so I'm not sure where stuff is going wrong. Like I said, the other two classes work perfectly.

Comment: Please provide **all** the code that is required to trigger the compile error. You shouldn't expect that people can give you 100% answers when you only provide 50% input.

Comment: What is the actual problem ?

Comment: By the name of your question, I assume that you're trying to call `FileAnalyzer.analyzeFile` instead of making an instance of `FileAnalyzer` and calling `fileAnalyzerObject.analyzeFile`.

Comment: The above comment sounds right. You can access it by instantiating the object and then calling the method or by making the method statically accessible.

Answer (score 2):

From,

> Static Error: No method in static FileAnalyzer has name 'analyzeFile'

I am assuming you are calling analyzeFile in following way

```
FileAnalyzer.analyzeFile();
```

Since `analyzeFile` is not static, You need to create object of `FileAnalyzer` to call `analyzeFile` method.

```
FileAnalyzer analyzerObj = new FileAnalyzer();
```

now you can call `analyzeFile()` on `analyzer` reference.

```
analyzerObj.analyzeFile();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Silly mistake on my part.